# Order of a subgroup H in a multiplicative group.

Tags: group-theory

> Let $G$ be the group of all $2 \times 2$ matrices $\left(\begin{array}{c c}a & b \\ c & d\end{array}\right)$ where $ad-bc \ne 0$ and $a,b,c,d$ are integers modulo 3, relative to matrix multiplication. Show that $o(G) = 48$. Now, If we modify the example of G by insisting that determinant = 1; then what is |G|?

I read a solution that says since this subgroup H of determinant 1 has index 2 (*), the order of this subgroup is 24 . But i am a little confused

(*) Why does this subgroup H has index 2? Because 1H forms a coset belonging to G?
But any other subgroup forms it too, no?

Comment: note that the determinant of an element of $G$ is $1$ or $-1$; there is only one coset of $H$ besides $H$

Comment: what is o(G)? (i'll delete this comment as soon as one answer)

Comment: order of $G$ (i.e., number of elements)

Comment: this is a very strangely worded problem *"Let $G$ be the group of all $2 \times 2$ matrices... where $ad-bc \ne 0$"* it should be understood that if the binary operation is multiplication, then the determinant must be a unit-- specifying the determinant is non-zero doesn't give you anything and the problem oddly does not specify whether the ring is $\mathbb Z$ or $\mathbb F_3$-- the latter is a nicer but it doesn't really matter here.

Answer (score 2):

An invertible matrix with integer entries has a determinant that is an invertible element of $\mathbb Z$, i.e. belongs to $L=\{-1,1\}$. Now, the determinant is a group homomorphism $\varphi$ between $G$ and the group $(L, \cdot)$. According to the first group homomorphism theorem, $\varphi$ induces an isomorphism between $G/H$ and $L$ where $H$ is the kernel of $\varphi$.

Therefore $H$ is a subgroup of index $2$ in $G$ as the order of $L$ is equal to two.